# Integral of $f^2$ exists, but integral of $f$ doesn't.

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm looking for function $f:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$, such that $\int f^2$ exists, but $\int f$ doesn't.

Is it fine to take $f(x)=1$ where $\frac{1}{2}<x<1$, and  $f(x)=-1$ where $0<x\leq\frac{1}{2}$?

Thank you.

Comment: In your example, both integrals exist. $0$ is a number that exists. It is very real.

Comment: "Exists" in what sense?  Are you talking about Riemann integrals, improper Riemann integrals, or Lebesgue integrals?

Comment: Riemann integrals.  Dirichlet function will work, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Dirichlet function will not work but a modified one maybe:
Let $$
f(x)=\begin{cases}1 & \hbox{ for } x\in (R\setminus Q)\cap(0,1)\\
-1&\hbox{ for } x\in Q\cap (0,1)
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is not Riemann integrable (see Dirichlet function) but $f(x)^{2}\equiv 1$ and therefore Riemann integrable over (0,1)...

If we would use the Lebesgue integral it would be impossible to find such a function, since $L^{2}(0,1)\subset L^{1}(0,1)$.

Comment: It will not change anything since in $L^{p}$ theory the boundary here $0$ and $1$ has Lebesgue measure zero...so in general you always have open sets...(we would be in a space with equivalence classes and two functions are identical there if they are identical up to a set of Lebesgue measure zero).

Comment: We can achieve the same thing with Lebesgue integrals by letting $A \subseteq [0,1]$ be nonmeasurable, letting $f(A) = \{1\}$, and $f([0,1]\setminus A) = \{-1\}$. Again $\int f^2$ exists but not $\int f$.

Comment: thanks for the comment, you are right :), i silently assumed that the function is Lebesgue measureable... :).

Comment: Ah! I was going to write this one exactly.

Comment: @CarlMummert +1 for the simple and yet an awesome answer.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Since you're integrating only over $(0,1)$, then the only way for an integral not to exist is (assuming $f$ is well-behaved, e.g measurable) if $f$ blows up too fast. Given this, do you think it's possible for such an $f$ to exist?

Edit: My answer was for Lebesgue integration. I believe that other answers/comments address the Riemann case.

Answer (score 1):

Lebesgue's criterion states that a function is Riemann integrable on a bounded interval if and only if it is bounded and its set of discontinuities has measure zero. Make an example that is discontinuous on a set of positive measure.